# Multiple constructors / defaulted argument before non default

Tags: python, constructor

Well I tried the following:

```
def __init__(self, name, x, y, z, cg_x = 0, cg_y = 0, cg_z = 0, mass, inertia):
    self.ref_x = x
    self.ref_y = y
    self.ref_z = z
    self.cg_x = cg_x
    self.cg_y = cg_y
    self.cg_z = cg_z
    self.name = name
    self.mass = mass
    self.inertia = inertia
```

As expected python complains that the constructor is incorrectly formed.

However how would I reshape this? I really really do try to prevent (A) moving cg_x/y/z after the mass/inertia. And (B) I still wish to provide the option of not having to define those.

Comment: Minimal test case please.

Comment: Show how you want to call this. With either 6 positional arguments or 9, and Python figures out that #5 and #6 are `mass` and `inertia` if there are only 6? With `mass` and `inertia` as keyword arguments? Something different?

Comment: @abarnert Ideally I would do some trickery with function overloading. Or I would depend on RTTI. Or as said keyword parameters (those become quickly verbose though ;P).

Comment: @paul23: Well, first, you can do RTTI, and far better than in C++ (which I assume is the language you're coming from?), because values carry fully-introspectable types around. But how would that help you here? And how would static overloading help either? As far as I can tell, all of your parameters, except `name`, appear to have the same type, so all you can distinguish between is a string and 5 numbers, a string and 6 numbers, … a string and 9 numbers. The types don't do any good at all. If you can show how you'd write this in C++, we can show how to do that in Python or explain why not.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can specify `mass` and `inertia` as [keyword-only arguments](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).  In Python 2 you would have to use `**kwargs` and manually extract `mass` and `inertia` from the kwargs.

Note that, with this setup, `mass` and `inertia` *must* be passed by keyword.  Conceptually, it is not possible to pass `mass` and `inertia` positionally unless values are also passed for all of your `cg_` arguments.  If you want to, say, pass a value for `mass` but not `cg_x`, your only option would be something like `foo('name', 'x', 'y', 'z', mass=0, inertia=0)`.  It's not possible in Python to define a function with arguments that "only sometimes" must be passed by keyword, so if there is any situation in which the arguments must be passed by keyword, you must make it so they are always passed by keyword.

Comment: Isn't there a way to introduce typing to do this? ... I suppose keywords are a form of typing

Comment: @paul23: How do you mean?  Python doesn't allow you to assign arguments by type.  You could manually check the argument types inside the function.  What types are you expecting for these various arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a `classmethod` that's an alternate constructor?

```
class SomeThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y, z, cg_x, cg_y, cg_z, mass, inertia):
        self.ref_x = x
        self.ref_y = y
        self.ref_z = z
        self.cg_x = cg_x
        self.cg_y = cg_y
        self.cg_z = cg_z
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.inertia = inertia
    @classmethod
    def no_cg(cls, name, x, y, z, mass, inertia):
        return cls(name, x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, mass, inertia)
```

Then you can do either:

```
foo = SomeThing('bar', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "10g", some_vector)
```

or

```
foo = SomeThing.no_cg('bar', 1, 2, 3, "10g", some_vector)
```

Alternatively add default arguments for `mass` and `inertia` then test for them

```
class SomeThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y, z, cg_x=0, cg_y=0, cg_z=0, mass=None, inertia=None):
        if mass is None or inertia is None:
            raise ValueError("Must provide mass and inertia values")
        self.ref_x = x
        self.ref_y = y
        self.ref_z = z
        self.cg_x = cg_x
        self.cg_y = cg_y
        self.cg_z = cg_z
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.inertia = inertia
```

Answer (score 0):

You claim you'd do this with overloading in (I assume) C++. But all of your parameters except `name` appear to be the same type. So clearly you're just overloading on the *number* of parameters, not the types. Something like this:

```
ClassName(string name, double x, double y, double z,
          double mass, double inertia) :
    name_(name), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z), 
    cg_x_(0), cg_y_(0), cg_z(0), 
    mass_(mass), inertia_(inertia) {}
ClassName(string name, double x, double y, double z,
          double cg_x, double cg_y, double cg_z,
          double mass, double inertia) :
    name_(name), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z), 
    cg_x_(cg_x), cg_y_(cg_y), cg_z(cg_z), 
    mass_(mass), inertia_(inertia) {}
```

And you want to know how to do something similar in Python.

The best way is probably this:

```
def __init__(self, name, x, y, z, *args):
    self.name, self.x, self.y, self.z = name, x, y, z
    if len(args) == 2:
        self.cg_x = self.cg_y = self.cg_z = 0
        self.mass, self.inertia = args
    else:
        self.cg_x, self.cg_y, self.cg_z, self.mass, self.inertia = args
```

Although you could instead do something like:

```
def __init__(self, name, x, y, z, cg_x_or_mass, cg_y_or_inertia,
             cg_z=None, mass=None, inertia=None):
    self.name, self.x, self.y, self.z = name, x, y, z
    if cg_z is None:
        self.cg_x = self.cg_y = self.cg_z = 0
        self.mass, self.inertia = cg_x_or_mass, cg_y_or_inertia
    else:
        self.cg_x, self.cg_y, self.cg_z = cg_x_or_mass, cg_y_or_inertia, cg_z
        self.mass, self.inertia = mass, inertia
```

Either way, however, this is a bit ugly. Overloading is *always* a bit ugly in Python; you're encouraged to use keyword arguments or alternate constructors, or in some cases to set some of the "optional" attributes after construction. But it's sometimes useful.

---

You also mentioned RTTI. Python's RTTI is *much* better than C++'s. You can write `type(spam)` for any object, and get back a class object (an instance of `type` or some other metaclass); you can examine its `__dict__` with the `vars` function, you can use the `inspect` module to do all kinds of things to the object or its type, etc. Or, with third-party modules, you can get Dylan-like or Common Lisp-like multiple dispatch (like virtual functions, but switching on the types of all of the arguments, not just `self`). But I'm not sure how you'd actually use any of that here. If the runtime types of the arguments were somehow relevant, that would be easy; for example `isinstance(cg_x_or_mass, int)` will tell you whether `cg_x_or_mass` is an `int` or not. But I don't know what you'd do with that.

Comment: Well with larger scripts I tend to create different types of for different units.. As you can't compare a mass with a length, or an amperes with newtons (there's always a "conversion" necessary).. It helped me often to prevent mixing up the order of variables when passing to functions...

Comment: @paul23: Sure, unit types can be useful, but I don't see how RTTI with unit types would help here in C++. Can you just show us the C++ code you'd write, instead of making us guess at what you intend, show how to translate that into Python, and then do it all over again if we guessed wrong, as I asked in a comment on the question?

Comment: No I haven't used it, the comment was along the lines of "potentially a division can be made through that"; especially considering python is interpreted so type information and the like I expect to be more easy to use/access.

Comment: @paul23: My point is that I don't believe there's a way to make this cleaner or more readable with RTTI; even in C++, the fact that `cg_x` and `mass` are different types at runtime is less useful than the fact that there are different numbers of parameters, or that they have different static types. If you can show me a way that RTTI would be useful in C++, I can help you adapt that way to Python, but if no such a way exists in the first place, there's nothing to adapt.